# Java Scanner Class Text Input Limit

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I was wondering if there was a character limit for pasting text using the Java scanner class. I am running a quick word count algorithm, and it gets it correct with shorter phrases, but if I tried pasting in like a paragraph of say, 300 words, it seems to not be working correctly.

Comment: Sorry, but how can we help? There is nothing to debug or something

Comment: No. You may need to check your line endings or your buffering (if you're using `new Scanner(InputStream)` or `new Scanner(ReadableByteChannel)`, but these are not concerns of the Scanner class.

Comment: `java.util.Scanner` has nothing to do with pasting text. Your question remains obscure.

Comment: @EJP The scanner gives you the ability to input text into your program....so yes it does

Comment: @NabinKhadka Just asking a question about how something works, that's all